# alinear DateTime al centro dentro <div>

Tags: php

Estimados como puedo agregar un datetime dentro de un div y alinearlo al centro?
Les dejo las lineas de codigo que tengo.

```
<?php
 $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Chile/Continental'));
  echo "<div align=\"center\"> La hora local es :  $hora->format('H:i a') </div><br>";
?>
```

El resultado me lo da centrado pero de la siguiente forma

> La hora local es : ('H:i a')

Adjunto el error que me da:

> Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$format in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hace falta concatenar la variable a tu instrucción de impresión, para que de este modo se lea como un valor dinámico y se muestre el valor calculado, que sería la fecha formateada, además de eso puedes optar por usar la sintaxis de `{$hora->format('H:i a')}`

```
<?php
 $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Chile/Continental'));
  echo "<div align=\"center\"> La hora local es :{$hora->format('H:i a')}</div><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, la primera forma me resulto, con la segunda no me alinea al centro.

Comment: Ok edito y dejo la opción que te sirvio @BrunoOviedo